# Post Params not being sent to web server using HttpPost

Tags: android, android-asynctask, http-post

For some reason I can not get my async task to pass along the post params I set. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my onClick which calls the thread. Please note that customerInfo is not null, and each index has a value.

**EDITED:** moved client and post declaration into doInBackground and took out extra, unneeded thread.
**EDITED2:** Apparently when hitting a subdirectory on your web server, and you declare your url like

```
 http://IP/subDirectory
```

without the trailing "/" apache doesn't pass the parameter to your index.php.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new RegisterPost(progress).execute();
        }
```

Here is my doInBackground

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String[] customerInfo = getRegistrationInfo();
        // Post
        // Send info to tmiszone
        String url = "http://SERVER_ADDRESS/"; // I had to add index.php to my url to get around the issue.
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        post = new HttpPost(url);
        // Set post parameters
        List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("salesCode", customerInfo[0]));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstName", customerInfo[1]));
        pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastName", customerInfo[2]));
        try {
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Make connection
        try {
            response = client.execute(post);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e){
            // TODO handle
            response = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO handle
            response = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO handle
            response = null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here is my php code.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
    error_log("hit by app");
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
        error_log("// ".$key." ".$value);
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Now in my apache log I see the "hit by app" message, but nothing else. And my app gets an empty html page with just the html and body tags as expected from the php code.

Comment: fyi - you shouldn't be creating a thread in doInBackground, you're already in a separate thread at that point. Also, I would construct the HttpPost and DefaultHttpClient within doInBackground, and pass customerInfo to the execute method of the AsyncTask.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the extra thread. I will correct that, and give your suggestion a try.

Comment: I have edited my code to try what you suggested. Is the above what you where talking about? Anyway I am getting the same result.

Comment: hmm just to make sure i'd step through the code and make sure there's no exception being thrown, and then i'd hook up the device you're trying this on to a proxy such as Charles Proxy to see what the request looks like (if it's an HTTP POST with params, etc)

Comment: I don't see anything in my logcat anyways, and my try/catch statements should catch any exceptions thrown by this process.

Comment: yeah, and perhaps that's the problem, an exception is being thrown and you're just swallowing it without logging it, etc

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40014/discussion-between-elitetech-and-sam-d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I faced had to do with my URL. my url was like

```
http://ip_address/testbed
```

the page I was hitting was index.php inside the testbed directory. Since I didn't put trailing "/" apache wasn't sending the parameters to the page during the automatic redirect. Add the "/" resolved the issue. Thank you Sam_D for your help.